# Opencart Checkout Mail Showing Three Times subtotal, total

Tags: opencart

When I am booking a order in opencart 2.2.0.0 then giving me three times subtotal, total and free shipping.

I have changed my model `order.php` to fresh file. Still I am getting same result.

If anyone have idea how to resolve it please share.

This image shows a error in opencart order booking format:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resetting your template files to default copies as well? Do you have any OCmod/VQmod extensions installed?

Comment: yes i have installed but i removed all files still it is showing same .please help me to correct it..